# Java 11: Kerberos using GSS API

Tags: kerberos, java-11, gssapi

I'm upgrading a project to Java 11. I realized that some of the internal packages such as `sun.security.krb5.Config` & `sun.security.krb5.KrbException` are no longer "visible" due to modules.
Few examples of how the codebase is consuming these packages are below:

```
Exception cause = ExceptionUtils.findCause(ne, KrbException.class);

LoginException le = (LoginException) ne.getCause();
                if (le.getCause() instanceof KrbException) {
                    KrbException ke = (KrbException) le.getCause();

try {
                    sun.security.krb5.Config.refresh();
                } catch (KrbException e) {
//log something
}
```

I read that these internal packages are supposed to be implemented using GSS APIs.

I have been going through the GSS classes and tutorials but couldn't find anything on replacing the internal packages mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the LoginException as-is. JAAS is supposed to abstract from everything. You just have bad code.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by taking the LoginException as-is? Do you mean I should just replace KrbException with LoginException?
Also, what about `sun.security.krb5.Config.refresh();` this is an internal API refernce as well.

Comment: First of all, there is now a refresh config property on the `Krb5LoginModule`: `refreshKrb5Config`. You are going through several levels of abstraction. You don't interact with Kerberos directly, therefore you must *not* use internal exceptions or even worse internal APIs. This makes code non-portable or brittle. [Here](http://tomcatspnegoad.sourceforge.net/xref/net/sf/michaelo/tomcat/authenticator/SpnegoAuthenticator.html#L117) is a sample how one should use it. When you are using MIT Kerberos you never get Kerberos internal errors too, just GSS-API status codes and some mech-specific ones.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that implementation. I think I understand it a bit better now. However, from official docs I see `refreshKrb5Config: Set this to true, if you want the configuration to be refreshed before the login method is called.` Is there a way to manually trigger config refresh apart from the login flow?

Comment: I understand now, I can just trigger a dummy login to reload the config file.

Comment: There is none and why do you need it if the module refresh before login anyway?

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I got it now. Just one last this is there a way to extract the underlying kerberos error code and the exception message from  Login Exception?

Comment: Unless `getCause()` does not contain it, no. You can also check the source code of the `Krb5LoginModule` on Github. Note that using GSS-API does not give you access to low level Kerberos errors too.

Comment: I think GssException.getMinor() does just that. From it's javadoc:
 `Returns the mechanism level error code for the problem causing this
     exception to be thrown. The minor code is set by the underlying
      mechanism.`

Comment: Yes, in a limited fashion.